# Python: How to set the variables of a class, based on a lookup to the column headers of a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, csv

I have a class `ETF` that has many variables. I just included three below for simplicity but there are actually close to 40:

```
class ETF:
    def __init__(self, symbol, name, asset_class):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.name = name
        self.asset_class = asset_class
```

There is another file in my project with the following code. The two `#CODE NEEDED HERE` comments are where my question pertains to.

```
import csv

# Open the file
data = open('db.csv')
csv_data = csv.reader(data) # csv.reader

# reformat it into a python object list of lists
data_lines = list(csv_data)

headers = data_lines[1] # Retrieving the column headers

# Find the Index positions in headers for each ETF class attribute
#CODE NEEDED HERE

# create ETF objects for each line in the file
for line in data_lines[2:]:
    # CODE NEEDED HERE
    # Lookup the column header based on the
```

I also have two spreadsheets. One spreadsheet is called `db.csv` and contains the information we will be using to create `ETF` objects.  Each row in this csv will be it's own `ETF` object. The column headers on the CSV file do do not exactly match the variable names in the `ETF` class and not every column is used. For that reason, I have a second spreadsheet called `column_reference.csv` which I will use to map the column names in `db.csv` to the `ETF` variable names.

See table below for an example of the `column_reference.csv` file:

[image: column_reference.csv]

Please see the image below as an example of the `db.csv` file:

[image]

What code would you use to most efficiently map the column headers and create ETF objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a series of nested for loops to create lists of each CSV row to accomplish this in the shortest amount of time possible. The `pandas` solution was too time consuming

```
import csv
from ETF import ETF


# Open the file
data = open('db.csv')
csv_data = csv.reader(data) # csv.reader

# reformat it into a python object list of lists
data_lines = list(csv_data)
print(type(data_lines))


# Creating a hash map of the column_reference.csv file
name_map = []
with open('column_reference.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = line.split(',')
        old = tokens[0]
        new = tokens[1]
        name_map.append([old, new])

# Retrieving the column headers of the database file
counter = -1
for i in data_lines[1]:
    counter = counter + 1
    for j in name_map:
        if j[0] == i:
            j.append(counter)

# Creating ETF objects based on the indexes of the columns in the database
for line in data_lines[2:]:
    # Lookup the column header based on the
    etf_characteristics = []
    for i in name_map:
        etf_characteristics.append(line[i[2]])
    this_etf = ETF(*etf_characteristics)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to create a dataframe out of the csv and [`df.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to iterate over the rows and initialize objects by them.
By manipulating the `df.columns` attribute you can set your custom column names.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I'm looking into this now

Comment: @FinDev If you think my answer is satisfactory, accept it as best answer

Comment: I will accept the answer shortly if I can get the solution working

Comment: what would you say to this post suggestion that iterating on Panda dataframes should not be used due to inefficiency?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/12963030

Answer (score 0):

This is the "Pythonic way":

```
columns = open('column_reference.csv')
csv_columns = csv.reader(columns) 

columns_dict = {}

for column in csv_columns:
    columns_dict[column[0]] = column[1]

for line in data_lines[2:]:
    values = {}
    for key in columns_dict.keys():
        p_index = headers.index(key)
        values[key] = line[p_index]
        ETF(**values)
```

Comment: there are about 40 variables in the ```ETF``` class, I'm not sure it makes sense to hard code this way given the number of variables. What do you think?

Comment: I edit the answer, a way to make this is using dictionaries

Comment: would you mind adding comments so I can understand your code better? I'm getting the following error message due to a lack of instantiation of the ```ETF``` object: ```TypeError: __init__() missing 30 required positional arguments```

Comment: I edit the answer, the purpose its save the properties in a dict and create an ETF(**values)